# Elasticsearch/Logstash Error: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver not loaded - can't locate mysql-connector-java-5.1.36-bin.jar on server

Tags: elasticsearch, jdbc, amazon-ec2, logstash

I'm trying to install the jdbc plugin for Logstash on a AWS EC2 server so I can query a MySQL database.
Logstash is working but I can't get the JDBC plugin to work. When I run Logstash I get this error:

> Error: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver not loaded. Are you sure you've included
>   the correct jdbc driver in :jdbc_driver_library?

I tried installing the JDBC plugin based on this:

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/getting-started-with-jdbc-input-plugin/77162

The install looked like it worked:

```
[ec2-user@ settings]$ sudo /usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-input-jdbc
Validating logstash-input-jdbc
Installing logstash-input-jdbc
Installation successful
```

But when I try to find the `.jar` file for the mysql connector it does not seem to exist on the system:

```
[ec2-user@ logstash]$ sudo find / -name "*connector-java*"
```

This is what my Logstash config file looks like:

```
input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "mysql-connector-java-5.1.36-bin.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://***:3306/website"
    jdbc_user => "***"
    jdbc_password => "***"
    statement => "SELECT * from runtime_ProdFull WHERE `MfPN` LIKE 'KO8%'"
  }
}
```

How do I identify the correct name for jdbc_driver_library and how do I find it's path so I can add it to my config?

Thanks,
Phil

SOLUTION:
I downloaded the latest platform independent version from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/ to my PC, unzipped the mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar file and uploaded to the EC2 server via WinSCP to /var/lib/logstash/.
Then changed the jdbc driver to:

```
jdbc_driver_library => "/var/lib/logstash/mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to download `JDBC` driver by yourself. Go to this [website](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) and download appropriate driver for your database and then put it somewhere in your `EC2`. Then you just have to specify path to the downloaded driver in this field `jdbc_driver_library` and you're good to go.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried using rpm to install the redhat rpm and got this error:

"warning: /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.AbpeJB: Header V3 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 5072e1f5: NOKEY"


So I manually downloaded the platform independent version, extracted the .jar file from the file, uploaded that to EC2 and it worked. I'm sure there's a nicer way from the command line but this worked for me.